# OOP PHP + PDO - Is this how it should be?

Tags: php, class, oop, pdo

I'm trying to create a simple example class before I start implementing the following into my projects and I would like to know if there is something I could/should improve. I will be very glad if someone gives me some input of how am I doing now.

Simple class example:

```
  // define class
  class User{
  private $UserID;
  private $UserName;
  private $Email;

  function SetUserID($NewUserID){
    $this -> UserID = $NewUserID;
    }

  function GetUserID(){
    return $this -> UserID;
    }

  function SetUserName($NewUserName){
    // update object
    $this -> UserName = $NewUserName;
    } 

  function GetUserName(){
    return $this -> UserName;
    }

  function SetEmail($NewEmail){
    $this -> Email = $NewEmail;          
    } 

  function GetEmail(){
    return $this -> Email;
    }

  public function SaveUser(){
    // check if user exists
    $User = new User();
    if ($User->UserExists($this->UserID)){
      // user exists - update him
      $Pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms;charset=utf8', 'xxx', 'xxx');  
      $Query = $Pdo->prepare("Update User set UserName = :UserName, Email = :Email, UserID = :UserID where UserID = :UserID");
      $Query->bindValue(':UserName', $this->UserName);
      $Query->bindValue(':Email', $this->Email);
      $Query->bindValue('UserID', $this->UserID);
      $Query->execute();
      $Pro = null;
      }
    else{
      // insert new
      $Pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms;charset=utf8', 'xxx', 'xxx');  
      $Query = $Pdo->prepare("Insert into User (UserName, Email) values (:UserName, :Email)");
      $Query->bindValue(':UserName', $this->UserName);
      $Query->bindValue(':Email', $this->Email);
      $Query->execute();
      // close connection
      $Pdo = null; 
      }
    }

  private function UserExists($UserID){
    // returns true if users exists, false if not
    $Pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms;charset=utf8', 'root', 'vertrigo');
    $Query = $Pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserID=:UserID"); 
    $Query->bindValue(':UserID', $UserID);
    $Query->execute();
    $Row = $Query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $Pdo = null;

    // get user
    if ($Row){
      return true;
      }
    else{
      return false;
      }
    }        
  }

function GetUserInfo($UserID){
  // open pdo
  $Pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms;charset=utf8', 'root', 'vertrigo');  
  $Query = $Pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserID=:UserID");
  $Query->bindValue(':UserID', $UserID);
  $Query->execute();
  $Row = $Query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $Pdo = null;

  // get UserInfo
  $UserInfo = new User();
  $UserInfo -> SetUserID($UserID);
  $UserInfo -> SetUserName($Row["UserName"]); 
  $UserInfo -> SetEmail($Row["Email"]); 

  // return UserInfo
  return $UserInfo;
  }
```

This is just an basic example of how I would like to work with it. What do you think I should improve?

Comment: Just curious, did you try to browse other similar questions?

Comment: This is better suited for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), which is for general code improvement questions.

Comment: You are making it really difficult to change the DB password...

Comment: Of course I did, I have also gone through several tutorials which differs and I dont know which one is the "best" one.

Comment: From what answer did you get that idea of connecting every time you have to run a query? Can you link please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any PHP application have to connect to database only **once**.
thus, your class have to use already created connection, not create it every time.

```
class User{
  private $UserID;
  private $UserName;
  private $Email;
  private $db;

  function __construct($pdo) {
    $this->db = $pdo;
  }

  private function UserExists($UserID)
  {
    $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM User WHERE UserID=?";
    $stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute(array($UserID));
    return $stm->fetchColumn();
    }        
  }
  // the rest going to use the same approach
}

$pdo = //see PDO tag wiki for theproper  example

$user = new User($pdo);
if ($user->UserExists($UserID)) {
  // whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. In this case - what would you pass in "New User($pdo) ? I mean - you have to create an new object of pdo to proceed? Thank you for all your help :-)

Comment: you have to create an new object of pdo when you are starting your application. And use that object all the way. not only for this particular class but for all the database interactions. No matter if you are using come classes or not.